# Why does a bank need to ask me who I worked for before I retired in order to cash two checks from the same person over $5,000

Tags: united-states

Why does my bank ask me who I worked for before I retired and what was my job  when cashing two checks over $5,000. when I have more than enough to cover the checks.  Last December I cashed the same amount and was not asked these question

Answer (score 3):

The bank asks questions because they are legally obligated to by anti money laundering laws.

When you deposit more than $10,000 in your bank account, then the [Bank Secrecy Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Secrecy_Act) applies. It doesn't matter if those 10k are in one transactions or in multiple transactions that appear related.

This means that your bank is obligated to file a "currency transaction report" to the Financial Crime Enforcement Network at the Department of Treasury. This does not mean that you *can't* deposit that amount of money. It just means that the DoT wants to know that you did.

This report requires various pieces of personal information your bank might or might not have on file. Your previous employer is actually **not** a required information for such a report. However, the teller filing the report is asked to states on the form whether or not *they personally* suspect the transaction to be something suspicious. Asking personal question that could explain the source of the funds can help them to make up their mind about whether or not they should check that box.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why is my financial institution asking me for identification and personal information?**
>
> Federal law requires financial institutions to report currency (cash
> or coin) transactions over $10,000 conducted by, or on behalf of, one
> person, as well as multiple currency transactions that aggregate to be
> over $10,000 in a single day. These transactions are reported on
> Currency Transaction Reports (CTRs). The federal law requiring these
> reports was passed to safeguard the financial industry from threats
> posed by money laundering and other financial crime. To comply with
> this law, financial institutions must obtain personal identification
> information about the individual conducting the transaction such as a
> Social Security number as well as a driver’s license or other
> government issued document. This requirement applies whether the
> individual conducting the transaction has an account relationship with
> the institution or not. There is no general prohibition against
> handling large amounts of currency and the filing of a CTR is required
> regardless of the reasons for the currency transaction. The financial
> institution collects this information in a manner consistent with a
> customer’s right to financial privacy.

source: [FinCEN - Notice to Customers: A CTR Reference Guide](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/CTRPamphlet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The $10,000 reporting threshold to the US government happens with cash transactions. If you are depositing the check into the bank, there would be no reason to report the transaction. Immediately pulling the cash out would cause them to report the transaction.

If you are depositing a large amount of money by check, they could put a hold on the amount to give them more time to make sure the check is good. In the past this was typical. Though they waived the longer time if it was a government check or a paycheck. Thus the question.

My current bank also limits the amount of checks that can be remote deposited each day.